# Java: Change an var's value (String) according to the value of an regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to know if it is possible (and if possible, how can i implement it) to manipulate an String value (Java) using one regex.

For example:

```
String content = "111122223333";
String regex = "?";
```

Expected result: `"1111 2222 3333 ##";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since the OP has redefined the problem (ie, a group of 12 digits which should be separated in 3 groups of 4, then followed by `##`, the solution becomes this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d)(?=(?:\\d{4})+$)");

String ret = p.matcher(input).replaceAll(" ") + " ##";
```

The regex changes quite a bit:

- `(?<=\d)`: there should be one digit behind;
- `(?=(?:\d{4})+$)`: there should be one or more groups of 4 digits afterwards, until the end of line (the `(?:...)` is a non capturing grouping -- not sure it really makes a difference for Java).

Validating that the input is 12 digits long can easily be done with methods which are not regex-related at all. And this validation is, in fact, necessary: unfortunately, this regex will also turn `12345` into `1 2345`, but there is no way around that, for the reason that lookbehinds cannot match arbitrary length regexes... Except with the .NET languages. With them, you could have written:

`(?<=^(?:\d{4})+)(?=(?:\d{4})+$`

Comment: As with your first answer, the lookbehind is an unwarranted complexity.  As you said, *validating* the string belongs in a separate step.  Once that's done, you can simply replace all `"\\d{4}"` with `"$1 "` and tack on the `##`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, and it is faster this way.

Answer (score 2):

With one regex only, I don't think it is possible. But you can:

- first, replace `(?<=(.))(?!\1)` with a space;
- then, use a string append to append " ##".

ie:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");

String ret = p.matcher(input).replaceAll(" ") + " ##";
```

If what you meant was to separate all groups, then drop the second operation.

Explanation: `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind, and `(?!...)` a negative lookahead. Here, you are telling that you want to find a position where there is one character behind, which is captured, and where the same character should *not* follow. And if so, replace with a space. Lookaheads and lookbehinds are anchors, and like all anchors (including `^`, `$`, `\A`, etc), they do not consume characters, this is why it works.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the solution you gave. But the example that i presented was not the best one. What i really want is to transform an string with 12 digits in an new string with 3 groups of  4 digits each one (dddd dddd dddd) and that ends with the ##, something like "dddd dddd dddd ##"

Comment: @user1106161 OK, see complement

Comment: Very nice, but you don't really need to use a lookbehind for this.  Just replace `"(.)(?!\1)"` with `"$1 "`.  And you're already leaving a space at the end, so you don't have to add one when you append the `##` part.

Comment: @AlanMoore well, I prefer not to consume characters when I can avoid it -- matter of taste, really ;)

Comment: If you like doing things the hard way, I can't stop you.  But you should at least grant equal time to the sensible approach. ;)